# Non-blocking nohup in bash function?

Tags: bash, blocking, nonblocking, nohup

I'm almost sure there is an easy solution to my following problem:

i have a bash script, let's say blob.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
function player_test(){
    if [ "$(pidof someplayer)" ]; then
      # do some stuff
      exit 0
    else
      nohup someplayer &
      exit 1
    fi
}

if $(player_test); then
  echo Message A
else
  echo Message B
fi
```

if the player is running, the method returns and I get Message A. Good.
If it's not running, it is started. However, the condition only returns after the player has quit and Message B is delayed.

Background:
I'm writing a script, that continously feeds tracks into the playlist of an audio program. in the corresponding function, the player is started with nohup, when it is not runnung already.

Best wishes...

Comment: Use `return` instead of `exit` in `player_test`, and don't call it in a command substitution. Use `if player_test; then` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nohup` command still has your stdout and stderr open.  Redirect to `/dev/null` like this:

```
nohup someplayer &>/dev/null &
```

and your function returns immediately.